# React returns image src as object

Tags: reactjs

I have a variable defined like this:

```
const team = [
  {
    name: "Foo",
    bio: "FooBar",
    image: { foo }
  },
  {
    name: "Bar",
    bio: "FooBar",
    image: { bar }
  },
];
```

Where the images are imported like this:

```
import foo from "../assets/foo.jpg";
import bar from "../assets/bar.jpg";
```

These are then passed to a component to be rendered, with:

```
<TeamRow team={team} />

The TeamRow component looks like this:

const TeamRow = props => {
  const items = props.team.map((item, index) => {
    return (
      <div className="col-10 col-sm-4 col-md-1 mx-auto text-center">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-12 teamMemberImage">
            <img className="img-fluid" src={item.image} />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-12">{item.name}</div>
        </div>
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-12">{item.bio}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  });
  return <div className="row">{items}</div>;
};

export default TeamRow;
```

The images fail to render. When I look at them in the dev tools, they have `src="Object object"`. The class that calls `TeamRow`, is the class in which `team` is defined. After defining it, calling `console.log(foo` returns the url pointing to the image, as expected. Somehow, in being passed to the second component, the expected behaviour ceases.

Strangely, earlier, I was using the react logo as a placeholder. So:
`import logo from "../assets/logo.svg";`, and this worked, but only if I rendered it as `src={item.image.logo}`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`{ foo }` is shorthand for `{ foo: foo }`, and `{ bar }` is shorthand for `{ bar: bar }`.

Instead of putting the image url in an object with a key that will be different for every image, you can set it as the `image` property directly.

```js
const team = [
  {
    name: "Foo",
    bio: "FooBar",
    image: foo
  },
  {
    name: "Bar",
    bio: "FooBar",
    image: bar
  },
];
```

Answer (score 1):

`team[0].image` is an object on the form `{"foo":"yourUrl"}` because you've wrapped `foo` in brackets, which uses the object shorthand syntax to create a property named `foo` with the value in variable `foo`. Remove the brackets around `foo` and `bar`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to put your image files alias names inside the {foo}, you can just write image: foo otherwise it will return as [object object].

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was struggling for the last four hours. but, it was a Next JS project so I need to put the image properties in an image component.
`<Image src={props.img} />` instead of `<img>`

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30792053)

Comment: NextJS works with <img> as well

Answer (score 0):

NextJS Caught me out, had to use `<Image />`, it did not work for `<img />` for this to work. I was using Material UI as wrapper CSS.

Comment: Is this an answer in itself, or just a "thank you, this worked" note on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70668334/5211833)? If it is a thanks note: please delete this. If it it indeed an answer itself, please read [answer] and edit it a bit for clarity.

Comment: Dont have enough points for either of those :( But is a combination of confirming the answer, but also suggesting this works more broadly for similar solutions, NextJs being unique vs React.