# SVG is being passed to img src as an object

Tags: reactjs, next.js, sanity

For a website using NextJS and Sanity.io,

I am importing an image locally

```
import large_logo from '../../assets/logo-large-1200x630.svg
```

and am calling it inside an img tag as src

```
<img src={large_logo}/>
```

However, the image is broken and not displayed.

The HTML is rendered as

```
<img src="[object Object]">
```

The only solution to this problem was to call the src of the "object"

```
<img src={large_logo.src}/>
```

However vanilla React [does not require us to call the src](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files/).

Does importing not work when using NextJS and Sanity?

Comment: I've looked at previous posts on this similar issue however, all of them describe the solution as not instantiating the image as an object ie. remove the {}. However, in order to render the image, I need it to be an JSX expression.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58169885/sending-svg-as-a-prop-gets-rendered-as-object-object
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53024792/react-returns-image-src-as-object

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/67641345/11613622, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68517122/background-div-images-not-displaying-when-setting-them-via-inline-styles-dynamic/68517270#:~:text=When%20you%20do%20something%20like%20this%20import%20img%20from%20%27path/to/img.ext%27%2C%20img%20is%20not%20the%20source%2C%20it%20is%20an%20object%20of%20type%20StaticImageData%2C%20which%20is%20defined%20like%3A

Comment: Does this answer your question: [Background Div Images not displaying when setting them via Inline Styles Dynamically | Next.Js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68517122/background-div-images-not-displaying-when-setting-them-via-inline-styles-dynamic)? The difference is that Next.js handles local images imports internally, and converts them to that object format. It's fine and expected for you to use `large_logo.src` with the `<img>` tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For `Next.js` you have to do something like this:

```
/* import Image component */
import Image from 'next/image';
/* import the required svg file */
import large_logo from '../../assets/logo-large-1200x630.svg
```

and then in `JSX`

```
<Image src={large_logo} />
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are using `Next.js` and wanna render an image that the size is more than 40*40(pixels) need to import the `<Image />` component from next/image.
That component optimize your image and render in your Application. So follow the example below to help yourself..

```
import Image from 'next/image';
import large_logo from '../../public/logo-large-1200x630.svg
```

inside your component you can add this code snipet for your image

```
<Image src={large_logo} alt="logo" width={200} height={100} quality={100} />
```

**First of all** you need to change the image directory of the image and put it in your public directory of your App, cause this is the default behaviour that `Next.js` needs for the images.

Inside your component you need to pass the `src` value, `alt` value and usually `height - width` prop or `layout` prop.

You can also need the official documentation for the  of `Next.js` : https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image